# Running multiple cassandra instances on the same IP address

Tags: cassandra

I have been able to successfully deploy multiple Cassandra instances on the same machine using different ports and loopback IPs. The question I have is why do I need to use Loopback IPs, why cant all the nodes share the same IP if they are all using different ports? I would like a detailed explanation about this if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

The address is used (not the address:port pair) internally in a lot of places to identify the node

Comment: Thank you for the response, can I please get a little more detail with a possible example?

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra, each and every node act like a master. Each master has a copy of a data .

Say for example , you have three nodes (1,2,3).You need 2 replicas of data always. What's the point of having both the replicas in the same node?( when you are pointing to the same node with 3 loop back addresses) . When your one physical machine dies, the entire cluster of three nodes go down with availability being a concern here.

Now place all three in different nodes.If 1 goes down , data is still available from any of the other two nodes(2 or 3 will still serve data).In this way , your cassandra cluster is made available.

Comment: I understand that. I am essentially trying to get behind the logic of how the IPs are tied to a node. This is for setting up a test environment, so I am ok with the nodes going down. I just need to know why they cant all use the same IP and just diff ports.

Comment: I ad already explained the purpose of this. If something is designed to serve a purpose,why should it support an anti-property. Hope you get it.